# How to create probability and scoring formulas?

Tags: probability, statistics, game-theory

I have seen questions regarding building scoring systems but the answers given apply only to the specific problem.

I am trying to understand how people can come up with equations that express the scoring based on multiple stats ex. [wn8](http://wiki.wnefficiency.net/pages/WN8). Also formulas that you plug in values and calculate the probability to lose based on weights.

How can I come up with those weights? How can I say that based on stats?

ex. Lets say I play a video game with multiple units. Every unit consists of people and those people have stats ex. strength experience in battle etc. How can I calculate my chances to win the opponent? Or at least build an army with the best probabilities of winning!(more programming np problem).

I am looking for the theory book/ideas to start searching, studying and thinking!

Thanks